# Unknown crash when using dynamic unsigned char array

Tags: c++, crash, char, unsigned

Could someone explain to me why this:

```
unsigned char * buf;
buf = new unsigned char[dataSize];
```

is crashing my c++ program? It's not giving me any error's so I'm really lost as to the reason why my program is crashing due to these lines of code. Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Here's the code for the project I'm currently working on, it's using OpenAL so you'll need it if you want to recompile the code.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <al.h>
#include <alc.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class SoundSource
{
public:
    ALuint Source;
    ALuint buffer;
    ALuint frequency;
    ALenum format;

    //position
    ALfloat sourcePos[3];
    ALfloat sourceVel[3];
};

ALCcontext * Context;
ALCdevice * Device;
SoundSource sound;

int endWithError(char * msg, int error = 0)
{
    cout << msg << endl;
    while(cin.get() != 10);

    return error;
}

bool initSound()
{
    Device = alcOpenDevice((ALCchar*)"DirectSound3D");
    if(Device == NULL)
        return false;
    else
        {
        Context = alcCreateContext(Device,NULL);
        alcMakeContextCurrent(Context);
        alGetError();
        return true;
        }
    return false;
}

string loadSound(SoundSource s)
{
    char type[4];
    DWORD size, chunkSize;
    short formatType, channels;
    DWORD sampleRate, avgBytesPerSec;
    short bytesPerSample, bitsPerSample;
    DWORD dataSize;

    FILE * fp = NULL;

    fp = fopen("test.wav","rb");

    fread(type, sizeof(char), 4, fp);
    if(!strcmp(type, "RIFF"))
        endWithError("Error: Not RIFF format");

    fread(&size, sizeof(DWORD), 1, fp);

    fread(type, sizeof(char), 4, fp);
    if(!strcmp(type, "WAVE"))
        endWithError("Error: Not WAVE format");

    fread(type, sizeof(char), 4, fp);
    if(!strcmp(type, "fmt "))
        endWithError("Error: Not fmt format");

    fread(&chunkSize, sizeof(DWORD), 1, fp);
    fread(&formatType, sizeof(short), 1, fp);
    fread(&channels, sizeof(short), 1, fp);
    fread(&sampleRate, sizeof(DWORD), 1, fp);
    fread(&avgBytesPerSec, sizeof(DWORD), 1, fp);
    fread(&bytesPerSample, sizeof(short), 1, fp);
    fread(&bitsPerSample, sizeof(short), 1, fp);

    cout << "Chuck size: " << chunkSize << endl;
    cout << "Format type: " << formatType << endl;
    cout << "Channels: " << channels << endl;
    cout << "Sample rate: " << sampleRate << endl;
    cout << "Avg Bytes per sec: " << avgBytesPerSec << endl;
    cout << "Bytes per sample: " << bytesPerSample << endl;
    cout << "Bits per sample: " << bitsPerSample << endl;

    fread(type, sizeof(char), 4, fp);
    if(!strcmp(type, "data"))
        endWithError("Error: No data");

    fread(&dataSize, sizeof(DWORD), 1, fp);

    unsigned char * buf;
    buf = new unsigned char[dataSize];
    fread(buf, sizeof(BYTE), dataSize, fp);

    alGenBuffers(1, &s.buffer);
    alGenSources(1, &s.Source);

    switch(bitsPerSample)
    {
        //8 bit
        case 8:
        {
            switch(channels)
            {
            case 1: s.format = AL_FORMAT_MONO8; break;
            case 2: s.format = AL_FORMAT_STEREO8; break;
            }
        }
        //16 bit
        case 16:
        {
            switch(channels)
            {
            case 1: s.format = AL_FORMAT_MONO16; break;
            case 2: s.format = AL_FORMAT_STEREO16; break;
            }
        }
    }

    alBufferData(s.buffer, s.format, (ALvoid *)buf, dataSize, s.frequency);
    s.sourcePos[0] = 0.0;
    s.sourcePos[1] = 0.0;
    s.sourcePos[2] = 0.0;
    s.sourceVel[0] = 0.0;
    s.sourceVel[1] = 0.0;
    s.sourceVel[2] = 0.0;

    fclose(fp);
    //delete[] buf;

    return "WAVE successfully loaded!";
}

void closeSound()
{
    alDeleteSources(1, &sound.Source);
    alDeleteBuffers(1, &sound.buffer);
    Context = alcGetCurrentContext();
    Device = alcGetContextsDevice(Context);
    alcMakeContextCurrent(NULL);
    alcDestroyContext(Context);
    alcCloseDevice(Device);
    cout << "OpenAL sound closed!" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    string result;

    if(initSound())
    {
        cout << "Sound Context and Device up!" << endl;
        result = loadSound(sound);
        cout << result.c_str() << endl;
        alSourcePlay(sound.Source);
        system("PAUSE");
    }
    else
    {
        {
            cout << "Sound Context and Device not made.." << endl;
            system("PAUSE");
        }
    }

    closeSound();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The error is not in those lines(unless you're allocating **lots** of bytes, which could cause a `std::bad_alloc` exception to be thrown). You are surely messing memory up before you reach that point. Use valgrind and you'll probably find the problem.

Comment: What's the value of dataSize?

Comment: @mfontanini It seems as if valgrind is only available for linux and mac (I could be wrong) thank you for the quick reply though!

EDIT: Btw I'm on windows.

Comment: @David 
The value of dataSize isn't consistent so it can be any value within the bounds of a DWORD or a unsigned long.

Comment: Have you overloaded Global new operator? and are you sure crash is within these 2 lines?

Comment: Try to whittle the code down to a minimal complete example that exhibits the error. Either you'll discover the problem along the way, or you'll arrive at something you can post and we can examine.

Comment: Is dataSize actually initialised, and is it **non-negative** and **non-zero**?  Do you have enough memory for the allocation requested?    How much memory are you really asking for?  Does it always crash?  Does it crash in both Debug and Release mode (assuming Visual Studio)?

Comment: @Anon Maybe it could be happening on the line below it which is     "fread(buf, sizeof(BYTE), dataSize, fp);" when I'm trying to read data into the newly allocated char array.

Comment: Ok I've posted the full source code for my project up above.

Comment: @xDarkShadowx, you might have done this, but is the memory allocation successful? Also, can you give value of dataSize

Comment: It looks like it's crashing right after the line "fread(&dataSize, sizeof(DWORD), 1, fp);" so I'm guessing the memory allocation fails. And the value of dataSize can be anything really.

Comment: That would be my guess, check for null pointer or better catch bad_alloc exception.

Comment: Hmm... I've swapped the "test.wav" file with another file and it seems to be working now. Must be the way some ".wav" files are formatted. (maybe some are little endian and some are big endian?) Thanks anyways guys! I really appreciate the help!

Comment: You should check the return value of each fread() call to make sure you have at least enough bytes in the file to be read.

Answer (score 1):

```
// replace this 
if(!strcmp(type, "XXXX"))
    endWithError("Error: Not RIFF format");
// with this 
if(!memcmp(type, "XXXX", 4))
    endWithError("Error: Not RIFF format");
```

since type is not \0 terminated

```
fread(&chunkSize, sizeof(DWORD), 1, fp);
```

tip: instead of sizeof(type) use sizeof(variable name)
e.g.
    fread(&chunkSize, sizeof(chunkSize), 1, fp);

if you later for some reason need to change the variable type it will not potentially blow up in your face

```
fread(&dataSize, sizeof(DWORD), 1, fp);
unsigned char * buf;
buf = new unsigned char[dataSize];
fread(buf, sizeof(BYTE), dataSize, fp);
```

never assume that what you read in is correct, instead check what dataSize is before you allocate.

it is also a good idea to avoid doing globals, you could easily create a struct with the variables that you need and return that from the function

```
struct context_t // or whatever u want to call it
{
  ALCcontext * Context;
  ALCdevice * Device;

};

bool initSound(context_t & c) {}
void closeSound(context_t & c) {}

int main()
{
  context_t context;

  if (initSound(context)) 
  {
  ...
  }
  ..
  closeSound(context);
```

Comment: This also worked quite well! And I was only using globals for quick testing purposes (seeing if the sound ACTUALLY worked) it'll all be going into structs and classes in the future though. But either way, thanks for the advice. :)